# IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection datasources

Tags: hibernate, persistence

17:03:38,942 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl] (MSC service thread 1-2) HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:jboss/datasources/studentDS

I'm getting this error .... May I know .. what and why this occur and solution also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate is asking the DataSource you specified for a connection but the DataSource says it cannot return one.  Beyond that, you have not given nearly enough information...